Does the President have to take the oath of office again when re-elected
Note: This question was prompted by Can a president-elect be sworn in BEFORE Jan 20th (but after electoral college vote certification on Jan. 6th)?
Article II Section 1 of the Constitution states

Before he enter on the Execution of his Office, he shall take the following Oath or Affirmation...

When a previous President is re-elected (whether an incumbent or as a former President), their oath for their first term is "before" they enter into their second term. So does that first oath still stand, or do they have to utter it again?
I'm pretty sure they do so traditionally, so I'm just curious if it's constitutionally required or just symbolic.

This seems more like a question for Law SE.

You can read the text, and I'm pretty sure that there has never been a Supreme Court case that addresses this. So what is done traditionally = "the way that everybody interprets the constitution" is what is "required".  An oath is symbolic, whether required or not.  It symbolises a promise to do something.  It isn't self enforcing.

Something being tradition doesn't imply it's based on interpretation of the Constitution. It's traditional for the State of the Union address to be delivered as a speech in Congress, but it's understood that the Constitution doesn't say it must be.

@kaya3 I considered that, but since the oath has no legal impact I thought it was more of a political issue.

The funny thing is that even though it's just symbolic, it's considered critical because it's in the Constitution. Remember when Obama had to retake the oath because he got the words out of order the first time? https://www.theguardian.com/world/2009/jan/23/barack-obama-oath-inauguration

Likewise, Obama is the 44th president, even though he served two terms; but the UK will count the first and second Johnson ministries (for ex.).

@AzorAhai-him- Good point. They're calling Trump the 45th and 47th president because his two terms are not consecutive.

@Barmar Obama retook the oath because the Chief Justice got the words wrong the first time.  But whether he had to retake it or not is far from clear.  It's entirely possible that the first oath was constitutionally sufficient, but the prospect of fighting over that in court was one that nobody wanted to entertain.  The practice of counting non-consecutive terms was established with Grover Cleveland, the first president to serve nonconsecutive terms.

The president (as with other elected officials) is sworn in for each term served. So yes, a re-elected president has to take the oath again.

This circular reasoning doesn't answer the question, which explicitly isn't about traditional practice.

@phoog: Tradition and custom are what we have., If you're looking for something else, you're wasting your time.

Why do they have to? The Constitution requires it for the first term, what requires it for subsequent terms?

@Barmar: the constitution is ambiguous. It merely says: "Before he enter on the Execution of his Office". It doesn't say whether 'enter' means the first time or every time, and historical convention has held that each election marks a new entry into office.

Which is what my question asked: Is it required or historical convention? Saying it's required because of historical tradition doesn't answer it.

@Barmar: yes it does, you just don't want to hear it. Which is not my problem…

@Barmar When an elected officials term is up they leave office, it doesn't matter if they got reelected and will stay in place as they are still assuming a new term. It is just like the rules that prohibit congress from raising their pay and requiring them to be reelected in order to have that pay raise.

Nobody really knows.  It's entirely logical to apply the oath of office for the first term to the second.  But, almost certainly, nobody will ever test this, because it's easy to take the oath again and the cost of the uncertainty that would result otherwise is too great: you don't want people challenging the legitimacy of a president nor of the acts of Congress signed by that president.
Consider the first inauguration of Barack Obama.  From Wikipedia:

Roberts and Obama made several mistakes as they recited the oath. The proper wording for the oath of office is prescribed in the Constitution:

I do solemnly swear that I will faithfully execute the office of President of the United States and will to the best of my ability preserve, protect, and defend the Constitution of the United States.

Roberts had practiced for the ceremony carefully. However, a memo noting his planned pauses in the recitation of the oath failed to reach Obama's staff before the swearing-in. As a result, Obama inadvertently interrupted Roberts during the first phrase, stating "I, Barack" while Roberts was finishing "do solemnly swear". Obama then correctly repeated the entire phrase "I, Barack Hussein Obama, do solemnly swear."
Roberts, who was not using notes, rendered the next phrase as "that I will execute the office of president to the United States faithfully," misplacing the word faithfully and saying president to instead of president of. Obama repeated, "that I will execute", then paused. Roberts attempted to correct the wording, but stumbled: "the off– faithfully the pres– the office of President of the United States." Obama then repeated Roberts' initial incorrect wording.

The next section of the Wikipedia article describes the decision to retake the oath and quotes Greg Craig, the White House counsel, as saying that the decision to do so was made "out of an abundance of caution."
Another notable historical datum is the opinion of George Washington on the question, which may be inferred from his second inaugural address.  The shortest ever given, it reads, in full,

Fellow Citizens:
I am again called upon by the voice of my country to execute the functions of its Chief Magistrate. When the occasion proper for it shall arrive, I shall endeavor to express the high sense I entertain of this distinguished honor, and of the confidence which has been reposed in me by the people of united America.
Previous to the execution of any official act of the President the Constitution requires an oath of office. This oath I am now about to take, and in your presence: That if it shall be found during my administration of the Government I have in any instance violated willingly or knowingly the injunctions thereof, I may (besides incurring constitutional punishment) be subject to the upbraidings of all who are now witnesses of the present solemn ceremony.

But this is not explicit nor entirely unambiguous.  The fact that Washington said this doesn't necessarily imply that the second oath was necessary.  He could have decided to swear the oath every morning; that wouldn't necessarily have made it obligatory for subsequent presidents to do so.
Since the tradition is so firmly established, and the consequences of failing to adhere to the tradition are so severe, the chance of anyone testing it is effectively zero.  There will never be a definitive ruling on the question.  Some may argue that it is required; others may argue that it is not, but we'll never know, because we'll never see what happens if a president should fail to take the oath at the beginning of a second term.
